# How to config simple login/pass authentication for kubernetes desktop UI

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

I'm pretty new in kubernetes, I just install kubernetes via kubeadm and run dashboard UI but can't config access to it. Following docs I add line `--basic-auth-file=/etc/kubernetes/auth.csv` to /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml, create file and put in one string like `pass,admin,admin`. But after that api server crashed and back to normal after deleting this string and reboot the server. How I can pass this parametr to api server without api server crashing, and maybe something else need add or remove from this file? Here is my

**kube-apiserver.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --admission-control=Initializers,NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PersistentVolumeLabel,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,NodeRestriction,ResourceQuota
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --advertise-address=236.273.51.124
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
    - --insecure-port=0
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/kube-apiserver-amd64:v1.8.0
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /healthz
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-apiserver
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki
      name: k8s-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ca-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/pki
      name: ca-certs-etc-pki
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your file for basic authentication `/etc/kubernetes/auth.csv` is not available inside kube-apiserver pod's container. It should be mounted to pod's container as well as certificate folders. Just add it to volumes and volumeMounts sections:

```
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/auth.csv
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/auth.csv
    name: kubernetes-dashboard
```