# How to access Kubernetes Dashboard as admin with userid/passwd outside cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

**Desired Outcome:**
I want to set up a CSV file with userids and passwords and access Kubernetes Dashboard as a full admin, preferably from anywhere with a browser. I am just learning kubernetes and want to experiment with cluster management, deployments, etc. This is just for learning and is not a Production Setup.  I am using Kubernetes version 1.9.2 and created a 3-machine cluster (master and 2 workers)

**Background/What I've done so far:**
I read the Dashboard README and I created an admin-user and admin-role-binding with the files shown below. I can then use the `kubectl describe secret` command to get the admin user's token. I run `kubectl proxy` on the cluster master and authenticate to the Dashboard with that token using a browser running on the cluster master. All of this works.

**admin-user.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
```

**admin-role-binding.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
```

I can login to the dashboard as admin IF:

1. I run kubectl proxy
2. I access the dashboard with a browser where I ran command (1)
3. I use the "token" option to login and paste the admin user's token which I get using the `kubectl describe secret` command.

What I'd like to do:

1. Set up a CSV file with userids/passwords
2. Login as admin with userid/password
3. Be able to login from anywhere

To that end, I created a CSV file, e.g. `/home/chris/myusers.txt`:

```
mypasswd,admin,42
```

I did not know what value to use for id so I just punted with 42.

I then edited the file:
`/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` and adding this line:
`--basic-auth-file=/home/chris/myusers.txt`

and then restarting kubelet:
`sudo systemctl restart kubelet`

However when I did that, my cluster stopped working and I couldn't access the Dashboard so I reverted back where I still use the admin user's token.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do here?
2. What id values do I use in the user CSV file? What groups would I specify?
3. What other changes do I need to make to get all of this to work? If I modify the apiserver manifest to use a file with userids/passwords, does that mess up the rest of the configuration for my cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one it is working for me. Taking reference from here.

```
  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/auth.csv
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/auth.csv
    name: kubernetes-dashboard
```

[How to config simple login/pass authentication for kubernetes desktop UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618383/how-to-config-simple-login-pass-authentication-for-kubernetes-desktop-ui/46633641)