# how does kube-apiserver restart after editing /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml

Tags: kubernetes

I installed kubernetes using `kubeadm`. And to enable basic authentication, I added `--basic-auth-file=/etc/kubernetes/user-password.txt` in my `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` and also mounted corresponding volume of type "File" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618383/how-to-config-simple-login-pass-authentication-for-kubernetes-desktop-ui)

Basic auth works now, my question is how does kube-apiserver knows to automatically restart Pod after I edit `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` on Kubernetes master host machine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

K8s control-plane components(apiserver,controller manager and scheduler) are **static pods** in the kube-system namespaces.

When you run following command

```
Kubeadm init
```

> Generates static Pod manifests for the API server, controller manager and scheduler

Kubelet periodically scan all of these files.

> Static Pod manifests are written to /etc/kubernetes/manifests; the kubelet watches this directory for Pods to create on startup.

I have attached the reference for further research

[kubeadm-init-workflow](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#init-workflow)