# Where is kube-apiserver.yaml?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, kube-apiserver

I would like to add a flag to the **kube-apiserver**.

So I logged in the docker container of the kube-apiserver on the master node and went on a mission to find `kube-apiserver.yaml`. I heard reports that it was located in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`.

Unfortunatly it was missing ! I only have a "SSL" directory in the /etc/kubernetes/" folder and the kube-apiserver.yaml is nowhere to be seen...

---

FYI :
Installed kubernetes 1.12.2 with Ansible playbook (kubespray).
Got 6 nodes and 3 masters.

Thx for your help

Comment: probably better to submit an issue to **kubespray** repo how to do that properly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `kube-apiserver.yaml` is in the directory you have specified - `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` but not on the kube-apiserver container/pod but on the master itself.

Comment: Ohhh indeed ! Thx ! Do you know If there is a process watching changes in this file ? If I change a value in there will it be taken into account and the kube-api-server rebooted automatically ?

Comment: yes, it should work like that - other behavior is a probable bug. You can find more information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007654/how-does-kube-apiserver-restart-after-editing-etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-api).

Comment: @Doctor make sure to plan you kubernetes version upgrade appropriately and make sure the changes are not overwritten by the upgrade process. I have not used kubespray, but kubeadm re-generate this file everytime based on it's own configuration.

Comment: Where would this be if I am using Docker Desktop for Windows 10 (using WSL 2 backend)?